# zsh: raise error when variable not defined

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

One nasty aspect with zsh (or with shell scripting in general) is, that if you mistype a variable name, and the resulting name doesn't exist, it is silently treated as empty string, which makes bugs hard to find:

```
if somecondition
then
  myvar=55
else
  my_var=66
fi
echo $MyVar # Oops
```

I know that this rule exists for compatibility with good old Bourne shell. I also am aware that I can explicitly catch this error when accessing a variable:

```
echo ${MyVar?NOT SET}
```

But if I do this on every variable access, it results in ugly code. Since I have the habit to explicitly initialize all my variables, I'm looking for some way that zsh automatically spills out an error message, when a shell variable or environment variable is accessed, which hasn't been set. Is there a way to do this? I already checked the `zshoptions` man-page, but didn't found anything suitable.

Comment: `setopt nounset`, or `set -u` which is portable. `man zshoptions`, search `UNSET`. Please try not to complain about a language in questions, because complaints usually only reflect ignorance and partial understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. BTW, I did not *complain* about a language. I just wanted to know whether this is possible, and explained why I would like to do it (because it might not be obvious).

Comment: BTW, re: the initial "making bugs hard to find" concern, you might consider using a static checker, such as that from http://shellcheck.net/ (which you *can* download from github, compile and run locally), which will let you find uses of undefined variables without the side effects of `set -u`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In not just zsh but other shells as well, `set -u` makes references to unset variables an error.

That said, many scripts will not work unmodified when using this option: `[[ $foo ]]` can no longer be used to check whether `foo` was provided by the outer environment, requiring `[[ ${foo-} ]]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To illuistrate [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s answer, and as an example of such a test (in a zsh shell) when `nounset` is used, you can consider this git commit (for git itself):
See [commit 34d8f5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34d8f5a8aa4aa17af3158f325173eb08c9c05eb1) (06 Jun 2016) by [Ville Skyttä (`scop`)](https://github.com/scop).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8162401](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8162401fb0ab16addc6e003a93b8d195cce3fad4), 06 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `git-prompt.sh`: Don't error on null `${ZSH,BASH}_VERSION`, `$short_sha`
>
> When the shell is in "`nounset`" or "`set -u`" mode, referencing `unset` or `null` variables results in an error.
> Protect `$ZSH_VERSION` and `$BASH_VERSION` against that, and initialize `$short_sha` before use.

```
-   [ -z "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || [[ -o PROMPT_SUBST ]] || ps1_expanded=no
+   [ -z "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] || [[ -o PROMPT_SUBST ]] || ps1_expanded=no
                       ^
-   [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || shopt -q promptvars || ps1_expanded=no
+   [ -z "${BASH_VERSION-}" ] || shopt -q promptvars || ps1_expanded=no
```